Ubuntu 24.04.1 - Samba shares are not displayed in the file manager
I have 2 NASs installed: TrueNAS (now for testing) and WDCloud (2Bay).
AFAIK shares are mounted correctly for both of them, but I don't see them as they used to be displayed on previous versions.
When mounted "manually" (using Other Locations in the Files) they are added to the GUI as expected.
//192.168.0.10/ArduinoCode /mnt/TrueNAS/ArduinoCode cifs credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nounix,vers=3.0 0 0

At the end I sudo mount -a or even reboot to be sure there are no other dependencies, but it still fails. What might be the reason for this?
Edi1 - Success TrueNAS mounts (Only. WDCloud was commented out)
guy@linuxPc:~$ df -h Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on tmpfs                              2.4G  2.3M  2.4G   1% /run /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  438G  267G  148G  65% / tmpfs                               12G   30M   12G   1% /dev/shm tmpfs                              5.0M   20K  5.0M   1% /run/lock /dev/sda2                          2.0G  215M  1.6G  12% /boot //192.168.0.10/PythonCode           16G  128K   16G   1% /mnt/TrueNAS/PythonCode //192.168.0.10/GeneralDocs          31G  128K   31G   1% /mnt/TrueNAS/GeneralDocs //192.168.0.10/ArduinoCode          16G  128K   16G   1% /mnt/TrueNAS/ArduinoCode tmpfs                              2.4G  140K  2.4G   1% /run/user/1000 

Please add the following info to your question:  1) do they show up in df?  2) if you manually mount with sudo mount  /mnt/TrueNAS/ArduinoCode (which should use the fstab entry) do you get an error and what is the error?  3) is there a more detailed error in /var/log/syslog

I spun up a copy of Try Ubuntu with Ubuntu 24.04.1 and created a mount point under /media/NAS/GnV_Common (which is a share on my Synology NAS) and using //192.168.1.117/GnV_Common /media/NAS/GnV_Common cifs username=[name],password=[psw],rw,uid=1000,gid=500
in fstab the share appeared in Files along with the other volumes.

Note that I didn't use vers=3.0

@user10489 1) yes. 2) no. 3) i;ll cechk

@graham just for the record, you are right for vers=3.0 (which was accepted by TrueNAS) and for WDCloud is vers=2.1, but - didn't solve the display issue. Thanks!

Things mounted under /media and /home/$USER will automatically be displayed in the side panel of the file manager and / or the desktop if your desktop allows that.
Things mounted anywhere else do not.
You you have two choices:
[1] Create a mount point under media like ... /media/TrueNAS/ArduinoCode and mount to that:
//192.168.0.10/ArduinoCode /media/TrueNAS/ArduinoCode ...

[2] Or keep the mount point under /mnt but add another option x-gvfs-show:
//192.168.0.10/ArduinoCode /mnt/TrueNAS/ArduinoCode cifs credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,rw,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nounix,vers=3.0,x-gvfs-show 0 0


changed to \media folder and it worked like a charm.
Tried to use x-gvfs-show on fstab without any succees. can you elaborate?

There are a set of x-gvfs-XXX udisks2 parameters that can be used in fstab as per: https://github.com/GNOME/gvfs/blob/master/monitor/udisks2/what-is-shown.txt I did verify this on my own system before posting. Not sure why it fails on yours.

Did you add it to each share definitions ? that is what I did

It's not in the share definition on the server. It's another option added to the fstab declaration: ..... ,dir_mode=0777,nounix,vers=3.0,x-gvfs-show 0 0 . Only needed when the mount point is not under $HOME or /media.
